# How can I provide a minimum height to ListView.builder's children which can expand automatically if the children require more space?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, layout, flutter-layout

I am using `ListView.builder`. In this, I need to set heights for the individual children. As of now, I'm achieving this using a `SizedBox`, but this doesn't give me the effect I want.

This is important because some of the children are column widgets like this:

```dart
return Column(
  children: List.generate(  //using List.generate for building the UI
    data.length,  //I don't know this length beforehand
    (int i) => Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 30.0, right: 30.0, bottom: height * 0.05),
      child: EducationMobileCard(
        //contents here
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

I want to wrap all widgets like this in a parent `ListView.builder`. Such that, when the user scrolls, each widget takes up the space that is required to fit its contents. Wrapping the widgets in `SizedBox` doesn't handle overflows. I've tried `ConstrainedBox` too. But it doesn't let the other parts of the UI access the vacant screen in case a widget hasn't taken up the entire maxWidth. It just simply keeps the space vacant.

This is the `ListView.builder` widget I'm currently using:

```dart
ListView.builder(
   itemCount: 7,
   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return SizedBox(height: height, child: widgetList[index]);  //height is the screen height here
   }
),
```

I simply want something that specifies the minimum space to occupy but lets the widget handle the maximum space to take within the `ListView.builder`.

**Edit:** This is the `EducationMobileCard` widget:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../custom/text_style.dart';
import '../theme/config.dart';

class EducationMobileCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const EducationMobileCard(
      {Key? key,
      //the required parameters
  )
      : super(key: key);

  final double height, width;
  final String insttution, location, years, grades, desc, image;
  @override
  _EducationMobileCardState createState() => _EducationMobileCardState();
}

class _EducationMobileCardState extends State<EducationMobileCard> {
  bool isHover = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: [
          //contents
        ],
      ),
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: isHover ? widget.height * 0.005 : widget.height * 0.01,
          bottom: !isHover ? widget.height * 0.005 : widget.height * 0.01),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        onHover: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            isHover = value;
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: widget.height * 0.04,
              left: widget.width * 0.015,
              right: widget.width * 0.015,
              bottom: widget.height * 0.04),
          width: widget.width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: isHover ? Colors.black12 : Colors.black45,
                blurRadius: 10.0,
                offset: const Offset(8, 12),
              )
            ],
            color: currentTheme.currentTheme == ThemeMode.dark
                ? Theme.of(context).cardColor
                : Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
              5.0,
            ),
          ),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/education/${widget.image}',
                        scale: 1.2,
                      )),
                ),
                FittedBox(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    child: text(widget.insttution, 25, Colors.white)),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
                  child: FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      child: text(widget.location, 10, Colors.white)),
                ),
                FittedBox(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 11.0),
                      child: text(
                          widget.years != ''
                              ? 'Years of study: ${widget.years}'
                              : '',
                          12,
                          Colors.white),
                    )),
                FittedBox(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    child: text(widget.desc, 15, Colors.white)),
                FittedBox(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    child: text(
                        widget.grades != ''
                            ? 'Grades Achieved: ${widget.grades}'
                            : '',
                        12,
                        Colors.white)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your card code?

Comment: Sure. @AfridiKayal

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ConstrainedBox` to set the maxmium and minimum hight.

*Refer the example below*

```
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: new BoxConstraints(
    minHeight: 35.0,
    maxHeight: 160.0,
  ),

  child: new ListView(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    children: <Widget>[
      new ListItem(),
      new ListItem(),
    ],

  ),
)
```

You can then use the shrinkWrap proper to wrap the unused space like this:-
`shrinkWrap: true,`

*Thank you*

Comment: It didn't work. The same problem that I've mentioned in my question.